# Openshift context path

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, war

I have deployed the war into tomcat 7 Openshift . Everything is fine and its running .[Myappp](http://www.eventsinbox.com) Here is my mapped web application.

I am  storing images in the dir  webapps->docs->images
But When I upload the image (with UI)  it doesnt appear on site and I cant even find where images are stored (I connected using FTP -filezilla ) 
Where my  deployed war file stored ? Do I need to make any changes in my code so to upload in proper dir of Openshift??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (~/app-root/data) to store uploaded images.  However, using Java this presents some challenges.  I would recommend that you read through this article (https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift), it should help you with dealing with user uploaded images.

Comment: ..thanks for the link ..I will go through it . Once I upload I would like show image on browser , I am using <img> tag in my  JSP page . Any idea on this??

Comment: Thanks :) My img are uploading now..I referred your link and changed my code . Post upload I can see my img file in data directory . Now  What change I have to make to show upload img on my web page?? current code <img src='<%req.path%>/docs/images/imgname.jpg'> .I tired this  <img src='/uploads/imgname.jpg' > also <img src='/data/imgname.jpg'>.. I tried different possibilities using firbug edit option. But nothing works .